# array.find function preventing access to parent class 'this' object

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I have this function inside an angular component. As soon as I attempt to query the "myData.Order3" array, I am unable to access "this" from within the 'find' function. 'this' reports as undefined, whereas other references to 'this' within the parent function are fine.

It's obviously a scoping issue, but having a problem fixing it.

```
public toggle():void {
    this.freq.toggle();
    this.checkState().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(this.freq.frequency);
        this.myData = response as ArrayCast;
        if (this.myData.Order3.find(function(ele) {
            return ele == this.freq.frequency; // <= "this" reports as undefined
        })){
                this.toggleStyle="ui-button-danger";
        }
        console.log(this.myData);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the Lambda expression `=>` instead of `function`

```
if (this.myData.Order3.find((ele) => ele === this.freq.frequency))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public toggle():void {
        this.freq.toggle();
        this.checkState().subscribe(response => {
            console.log(this.freq.frequency);
            this.myData = response as ArrayCast;
            if (this.myData.Order3.find((ele) => ele == this.freq.frequency)){
                    this.toggleStyle="ui-button-danger";
            }
            console.log(this.myData);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `this` causing the error is **not referring to the same object**. Luckily, there are a few ways to fix this.

1. Use arrow `=>` functions because they do not bind `this` upon creation. (Also, you have already used it when u called `subscribe` function.

`this.myData.Order3.find((ele) => ele === this.freq.frequency)`

2. Create a reference to `this` so you can refer back to the same object.

.

```
function foo() {
    var that = this;
    function bar() {
        console.log(that);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While proper answer is here, nobody explains why. When using `anonymous function` is in fact an `Object`, so you are creating new scope for `this` that's why we are loosing our "desired" `this` scope. There are few ways to assign proper scope for `this`. In my opinion the most clean way is using mentioned above [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is preserving current scope of `this`. There is also method with `.bind(this)` which is simply binding current scope to `function` so it looks like

```
array.find(function(el) { ... }.bind(this));
```

It's good way for compability since arrow function is `ES6` expression, so not every brwoser will handle this properly, so if you are not using polyfill (however as you are using angular you don't have to worry about this)  it's better to use `.bind(this)`.

There is also third option  some of the methods like `array.find, array.forEach...` has second argument `thisArg` which simply means you can pass there an `Object` and this will be your scope of `this`

### first option

```
if (this.myData.Order3.find(ele => ele == this.freq.frequency))
```

### second option

```
if (this.myData.Order3.find(function(ele) {
    return ele == this.freq.frequency; // <= "this" reports as undefined
}.bind(this)))
```

### third option

```
if (this.myData.Order3.find(function(ele) {
    return ele == this.freq.frequency; // <= "this" reports as undefined
}, this))
```